# Problem with Anaconda Powershell on Windows and establishing environments via .yaml files: "ResolvePackageNotFound:"

Tags: conda, snakemake, bioconductor

I am very new to anything with command lines and currently trying to establish a snakemake workflow from a git hub repository. The requirements given in the git-hub repository are miniconda and snakemake which I both installed on windows 11 (snakemake within an explicit conda environment).
Now I have to create multiple environments which are defined by .yaml files such as:

channels:

- conda-forge
- bioconda
- defaults
- default
  dependencies:
- minimap2=2.15
- samtools=1.9

The required channels are active within the snakemake environment as shown here:

conda config --show channels
channels:

- default
- conda-forge
- bioconda
- defaults

Although the initial plan was to stick to the suggested versions, to prevent issues in the downstream process leaving out the versions solved some problems, however I repeatedly get the following error:

"Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:

- samtools
- minimap2"

or equivalents - sometimes only few packages remain unsolved, sometimes all. Packeges affected are all where bioconductor ist within the path:
f.i.

- bioconductor-rhdf5
- bioconductor-qdnaseq
- bioconductor-rsamtools
  and so on
  as well as samtools and minimap2.

I tried installing some of the packages into a single environment which did not work either which makes me think that I might need some additional programm/package/channel to be able to install them...
I tried this at the very beginning so there are almost no other programms within the Anaconda Powershell and everythin in Conda is just associated with the described and published workflow.
Installing the packages in a single environment each would not help, since the snakemake workflow would not work as far as i understand. There is always a reference to singular environments.

Any suggestions? I would be greatful if possible suggestions would be in an understandable language, since I really do not have any idea besides the above described problem.

One suggestion I found in chats was install everything via pip, however the way it was written Im not sure if that was a joke...?

Answer (score 2):

If you check the channel for [samtools](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/minimap2) and [minimap2](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/minimap2) you can see that under installer there is no win version. You can see the window icon for [fastqc](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/fastqc) for example.

For me, I just install Ubuntu via WSL and run things from there.

Comment: Exactly. Bioconda does not support Windows - use WSL2 and install a Linux version of Mambaforge.